# AFNetworking and HTTPS

Tags: ios, objective-c, https, afnetworking

I googled around a little bit and read some SO posts, but I was still a little confused so I figured I'd post a question here: is making a request using HTTPS any different than making one using HTTP with AFNetworking? If so, what needs to be changed? Thanks!

Comment: no you don't have to change anything for making an HTTPS call. I am using HTTPS calls in my project and they all are working smooth n fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No change is required.

From a client perspective, using HTTP and HTTPS is the same with `AFNetworking` (and I'd say with any reasonable networking library).